# How to send same survey email more than once for each customer

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, history-tracking

We need to send same survey email for each event that we receive from our customers.

Example:

> John buys new furniture on Ikea for 3000€. We receive this event. We
>   send him loan offer for 3000€ with 150€/month 2 years
>
> John buys sofa on El corte Ingles for 1500€. We receive this event.
>   We send him loan offer for 1500€ with 50€/month 3 years
>
> John buys new car on Mercedes for 35000€. We receive this event. We
>   send him loan offer for 35000€ with 600€/month 6 years

All this events happens on same day.

Right now, if send to same customer 3 email surveys, only first email response is accepted by system. For other responces, we get:

> Thank you for responding to our survey. Our records indicate that you have previously submitted a response to this survey. Please click
>   on the button below to return to your email.

How can we configure to accept these 3 responses?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ET built in survey functionality is rather limited.  I've been faced with a similar problem before.  What I recommend is you make your own.  Make a landing page to handle your surveys, store the data in a data extension, and you won't have to worry about the survey functionality.